# How to subtract 5 minute from date

Tags: bash, date, datetime, subtraction

I have this data:

```
`date +%Y-%m-%d`" 00:00:00"
```

that return `2015-10-08 00:00:00`

I would like cancel 5 minute:

```
2015-10-07 23:55:00
```

Many thanks

Comment: `date --date "-5 min" +"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"`

Comment: Hello, this command returns    2015-10-08 00:00:00

Answer (score 2):

You need to subtract 5 minutes from a known point in time:

```
$ date -d "00:00:00 today"
Thu Oct  8 00:00:00 EDT 2015
$ date -d "00:00:00 today -5 minutes"
Wed Oct  7 23:55:00 EDT 2015
```

You just need to add your format string.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to subtract a value from the current time, although this should match the format shown in your question:

```
 date -d "-5 min" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

**Result**:

```
2015-10-08 15:26:13
```